# How to install t4Toolbox in Vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am beginner. I am trying to use T4template in Visual studio project.
I am using VS2010. 
I have downloaded vsix file from locaion http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f9bd62f-2505-4aa4-9378-ee7830371684
But it is for VS 2012.
Is it available for VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

On the link you provided there is written:

> SUPPORTS: Visual Studio **2012**

**However**, on the Web there are some compatible versions (outdated of course), for example [on CodePlex](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/30030)

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep look here: http://www.olegsych.com/2009/10/t4-toolbox-support-for-visual-studio-2010/ and in the author blog.

This version support well VS2010: http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/41443

CodePlex link: http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com

Don't forget to tank Oleg Sych for his great work!